# Deadlock with runBlocking(UI) - (Kotlin, Coroutine)

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I try to manage my threads for IO Processes. One of is for Realm usage.

like…

```
init {
        val ai = app.packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
        bundle = ai.metaData
        runBlocking(appExecutors.dbContext) {
            Realm.init(app)
        }
    }
```

It works fine if I set val dbContext as newSingleThreadContext(“databaseIO”)…
But I develop an android-library, so If there is an implementation of Realm on the app module, I need to set the usage on the same thread. And generally, everyone uses main thread to access to Realm. In that case I tried to set UI but it caused ANR. I can understand why it causes ANR, but I can’t find a proper solution for this scenario.

Note: if I use it with launch… it works for here. But on my RealmManager class I need to use runBlocking. So there is no way to use only launch…:slight_smile:
like…

```
fun getProfile(id: String): Profile? {
        try {
            return runBlocking(dbCoroutine) {
                val query = realm!!.where(Profile::class.java).equalTo("numbers.id", id)
                query.findFirst()
            }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            logger.e(TAG, ex)
            return null
        }
    }
```

or

```
internal val allProfiles: List<Profile>
        get() = runBlocking(dbCoroutine) { realm!!.where(Profile::class.java).findAll() }
```

Is there anything I do wrong way, or any advice for better implementation?

Comment: What is dbCoroutine? appExecutors.dbContext?

Comment: @qwwdfsad They are same thing, 
val dbContext: CoroutineContext = newSingleThreadContext("databaseIO"),